# error on double clicking the driver of ms access in ODBC datasource administrator

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2007, driver

Hi I was trying to connect to a table in MS-Access(2007) with perl. but each time I execute, I receive an error an `failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002)`.

Recently when I tried double clicking on the Driver in `ODBC datasource administrator` I found the error `The setup routines for the microsoft access driver(*.mdb,*.accdb) ODBC driver could not be found. Please reinstall the driver.` I tried installing drivers but still I get the same error.
Please guide me with my problem.

Comment: This isn't a perl question. This is a computer administration problem. A google search for your error shows many courses of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 64-bit system ,by default all the datas are linked on to the 32-bit. so we need to explicitly move datas from 64 to 32-bit.